# A vector of binary numbers to be used in runs.test

Tags: r, vector, format

I have been working through some data and want to get to the point where I use `randtests::runs.test` on the data. I have tried, but I do not seem to have the data in the wrong format. I can replicate the error in the following manner.

If I create a vector this way

```
x <- c(0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0)
sum(x)
runs.test(x, plot = TRUE)
```

the function runs without any problems, including creating the nice plot. However, if I do it this way it does not work. Note I converted the int to a numeric to ensure that R at least recognizes the data as being in the same format.

```
xx <- rbinom(16, 1, prob=0.5)
xx<- as.numeric(xx)
sum(xx)
runs.test(x, plot = TRUE)
```

Comment: Maybe typo? You have `runs.test(x, plot = TRUE)`, but are using vector xx.

Comment: Please clarify "does not work". An error message, an unexpected result?

Comment: What I was trying to allude to is that the output for the plot was very different and are the statistics. It seems @neilfws has identified why it happens. ie it is not a data format issue but rather an uneven split between the categories.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `runs.test` works in the first case because the number of 0, n1, equals the number of 1, n2, that is n1 = n2 = 8.

If you try running this code several times:

```
runs.test(rbinom(16, 1, 0.5))
```

you'll note that a statistic is returned when n1 = n2 = 8, n = 16:

```
data:  rbinom(16, 1, 0.5)
statistic = 1.0351, runs = 11, n1 = 8, n2 = 8, n = 16, p-value = 0.3006
alternative hypothesis: nonrandomness
```

otherwise the statistic is `NaN`:

```
data:  rbinom(16, 1, 0.5)
statistic = NaN, runs = 1, n1 = 0, n2 = 6, n = 6, p-value = NA
alternative hypothesis: nonrandomness
```

So if your aim is to generate a vector of 0 and 1 with equal counts of each, try something different to `rbinom`, for example:

```
x <- sample(rep(0:1, each = 8))
```

Otherwise, perhaps a different test that works with uneven splits is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for discovering the root of the issue. I will have to reassess how I use the data now